# How can I know if a decimal terminates?

Tags: c#, algorithm, class

I'm creating a program where the kids must convert a decimal value (I.E. 0.xxxx - precision 4) to a fraction.

I need to know whether a fraction terminates or not, I mean:

`1/9 ~ 0.111` but `111/1000 = 0.111`

I'm creating a `Fraction` class, but I have no idea how to distinguish between these two cases.

```
public class Fraction
{
    #region Fields

    private int _numerator;
    private int _denominator;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Numerator
    {
        get { return _numerator;}
        set { _numerator = value;}
    }

    public int Denominator
    {
        get { return _denominator;}
        set { _denominator = value;}
    }

    public decimal DecimalValue
    {
        get { return (decimal)_numerator / _denominator; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public Fraction() { }
    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        this.Numerator = numerator;
        this.Denominator = denominator;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's infinite, then the Denominator is 0 or very nearly 0, depending on precision.  Check for 0?

Comment: I'm sorry, are you trying to figure out whether your fraction is 0.1 recurring? Like 0.111111... ? Or are you trying to figure out if the resulting fraction should actually be a representation of infinity? I'm a little confused at the moment.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal

Comment: "A fraction in lowest terms with a prime denominator other than 2 or 5 (i.e. coprime to 10) always produces a repeating decimal."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the denominator's prime factorization.

If all the prime factors are either 2 or 5, it will have a finite decimal representation.

If it has a prime factor that is not 2 or 5, then it will be a recurring decimal.

(It works because 10's prime factors are 2 and 5.)

*edit - And check that `numerator % denominator` is not 0, as Stefan H points out.*

Comment: That seems incomplete...  14/7 does not have a recurring decimal.  You are missing a check for numerator mod denominator equaling 0

Comment: exactly - hence why your answer is incomplete.  That is all I was pointing out.

Comment: thanks guys! here is the code..                 if (Numerator % Denominator == 0)
                    return false;

                var primes = Denominator.Primes();

                foreach (int n in primes)
                {
                    if (n != 2 && n != 5)
                        return true;
                }

                return false;

Answer (score 3):

I've not done an exhaustive analysis on this to prove or disprove the following, but off the top of my head the following seems to work for whole numbers ....

If there is no remainder, then you do not have an issue to worry about.
If there is a remainder and the denominator has factors other than 2's and 5's, then you will have a repeating fraction.

A little tweaking of those rules may be required if the denominator is a decimal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: His code shows numerator and denominator to be integers without any decimal part. Just noting it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting correctly, you want to convert a fraction into a repeating decimal, and you are having trouble computing the repeating portion.

[Here's a good explanation of how to do that.](http://fcd3.org/misc/decimals/methods.html)